# Accessing the Java application without context path

Tags: java, contextpath

We need to have a context path to deploy the Java application and access it through the browser. We have nearly 10 applications on Oracle Application server. We would like to work our applications without context path. i.e.; we would like the application server to look at the corresponding application based on the domain name.

I know this can be done as Google app engine is doing the same when users deploy their applications. Context path of these application will be just "/".

Any ideas on setting this up on Oracle app server?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the Oracle Application Server being referred to, is the older Oracle Containers for Java (OC4J).

With OC4J, you'll need to put OHS (Oracle HTTP Server) or any compatible HTTP Server (Apache 1/2 works) in front of OC4J, and configure the HTTP Server to forward requests to OC4J (there are mod_oc4j plugins available for the same). Additionally, you'll have to configure the HTTP Server to serve multiple virtual hosts.

The same information holds good even for Oracle WebLogic Server.

You can find more information on the same in Oracle HTTP Server Administrator's Guide. The guide to version 10.1.3.1 is available [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28948/toc.htm); you might need to determine the appropriate version of OHS for your version of OC4J/WLS.

You could ask additional questions on OHS/Apache configuration on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Yeah you're right we're using the OC4J. Already we've OHS and we've all the virtual hosts and they're running. But all of them got their own context path. My question based on the domain name, can the OC4J point to specific application rather than using the context path.

Comment: @Santhosh, I think you need to look at rewriting URLs for this case.